# Last value in hierarchy of Dynamic parameters is not working in BO Central Management Console

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

I have a Crystal Report with dynamic parameters up to 4 levels (hierarchy of 4 levels) that is developed on version 12.3.0.601 which is working fine on my system. But when the same was uploaded on Business Objects Central Management Console first 3 hierarchies are populating fine but when comes to 4th hierarchy I am only getting the values that are linked to first value of second hierarchy.

Example:

If I take the example of the organization following is the hierarchy.

```
1st : business head  // One Value

2nd : Project head  // 4 values (p1,p2,p3,p4)

3rd : Team head     // 1 value

4th:  developer       // 2 values for every project head  that means total of 8 values.
```

If 2nd hierarchy is `p1,p2,p3,p4` then I am getting only `2 values of P1`, In the same way if 2nd hierarchy is `p2,p1,p3,p4` then I am getting only `2 values that is of P2`... but in real I need to total of 8 values because of all 4 values are selected at run time in 2nd level of hierarchy.

I have tried all possible combinations of dynamic parameters but nothing was working for me.

Problem is only in `Business Objects Central Management Console version is 3.1x` where the dynamic parameter is prompt is wrong and in dev system everything is correct.

Comment: About how many records are being pulled in at each hierarchy level?

Comment: @Ryan Less than 5 records.....

Comment: I know that BO has had many issues with cascading dynamic parameters in the past, and especially in XI/2008 (every BOE admin I've worked with has requested that we don't use these types of parameters because they're buggy), but I can't seem to find any solid documentation except for issues relating to version discrepancies and large record subsets. Maybe you'll have better luck looking...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ryan i am banging my head for last 2 days but unable to find any solution nor i could find any specific fix pack for this kind of issues....if you have any idea of the fix packs please let me know... as now i am sure this is not related to tool any more.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer so that it would be useful for someone who has the same issue.

Finally I was able to find the solution for the problem... It was the issue of service pack...

I was able to get the `SAP note` for the same issue.

Link for the note

http://sap-note.com/1494409.htm

According to the note problem was addressed in some of the service packs that are released for BO 3.1

Tested the same on `BO 3.1 SP7` and there I can't spot the issue and everything is working fine.

Thanks all for the help...

@Criag thanks for your suggestions on `Business View Manager`

Answer (score 1):

When you create D/C parameters in this manner (i.e. created in CR, then published to the Repository), there will be a set of objects (e.g. BusinessView, DataConnection, DataFoundation, DataElement, LoV, and ParameterSet) created for each report.  As you might imagine, this quickly becomes unmanageable.  To see this mess, open the BusinessView Manager, and review the contents of the 'dynamic parameter' folder.

A better approach is to use the BusinessView Manager to create a **limited** number of functionally-focused (e.g. Sales) BVs where you create all the objects manually, then assign the D/C parameter to a report using CR.

My guess, without being able to examine your situation in person, is either:

1. the query in the DataFoundation isn't doing what you want
2. the list-of-values server isn't refreshing the LoVs properly

Comment: Thanks @craig for your reply... your approach is one that I haven't tried... to be honest I am not aware of this... if possible can you please provide some more information about this... like where can I find the `Business View Manager` and how can I find the `Data Foundation` and how to check the query created by data foundation also what can be done to fix the issue?... Sorry for too many questions... Thanks

Comment: `update:` I was able to find the `Business View Manager` but I was able to find lot of parameter hierarchies.... finally able to find the hierarchy that I was looking for but unfortunately there were many copies of the same hierarchy... Can you assist me how can I find the correct one and what to do next when I find the correct hierarchy.. thanks

Comment: I wrote an application (MDB format) to do this.  It uses the BO SDK to find the linkages.

Comment: thats great... Is it possible for me to get that application?

Comment: Free for now: [lov-mapper](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/products/businessviews-lov-mapper/)  If it helps, free free to [gittip](https://www.gittip.com/craibuc/) me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... I am unsure whether I will be able to use your code as my company policy is restricting the downloads of files from internet and not providing the access as well... I can do it from my personal computer but will check the feasibility but thanks for your kind help....

Comment: I've started to migrate the MDB to a C# project [businessview-utils](https://github.com/craibuc/businessview-utils).  Feel free to contribute.

Comment: Issue is resolved.. please check my answer... Thanks for your help.